# Separating integer values from string

Tags: c#

Suppose I've strings like below:

1. `_4_5`
2. `_15_16`

Now I want them to separate and get the values in variables like

1. `i=4, j=5`
2. `i=15, j=16`

How it could be done?

Comment: Check out `String.Split`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string by underscores and pull out the parts:

```
string s = "_4_5";
string[] parts = s.Split(new [] {'_'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
i = int.Parse(parts[0]);
j = int.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Some things to add:

- error handling
- bounds checking (did I get two parts back?)
- number checking using `TryParse` (are the parts *really* numbers?)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to D Stanley's answer, if you are going to have an unknown number of variables (in other words, not just `i` or `j`), you could use this method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "_8_12";

        Console.WriteLine("Original ==> \"{0}\"", s);
        Dictionary<string, int> numbers = ParseNumbers(s);
        PrintNumbers(numbers);
        s = "_1_19_7";
        Console.WriteLine("Original ==> \"{0}\"", s);
        numbers = ParseNumbers(s);
        PrintNumbers(numbers);
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, int> ParseNumbers(string s)
    {
        var variables = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        char startVar = 'i'; // Start at 'i' Variable

        string[] nums = s.Split('_');

        foreach (string num in nums)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(num))
                continue;
            variables.Add(startVar.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), int.Parse(num));
            startVar++;
        }
        return variables;
    }

    private static void PrintNumbers(Dictionary<string, int> numbers)
    {
        foreach (var q in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", q.Key, q.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to have more than just 2 numbers per input line. So you can pass in strings like `_8_12` or `_8_12_13_19_25` or even just `_8`.